# How to restart a selenium webdriver that went down in an ongoing testing?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-grid

I have setup a selenium grid with 1 Hub and 2 nodes, each node with a capability to host 8 instances of firefox browser, so in total 16 firefox browsers are possible.

Following that, I am running a code which first creates 16 firefox webdrivers. Then goes through a list of websites and executes some task on each website by running that website in any of the 16 firefox webdriver that is available.

Now the issue I am facing is that while going through the list of websites, sometime 1-2 webdrivers go down (quits automatically, don't know why). I am trying to figure out that how to restart/repawn the webdrivers that went down so that the effective number of available webdrivers to perform the job remain at 16.

Here is what I have tried..

```
while executed_website_count != len(list_of_websites):
    
    # getting an available driver from the 16 drivers we had created
    driver = get_driver()
    
    # getting the next website
    current_link = get_link()
    
    # if the driver is dead, it will throw an error
    try:
        driver.get(current_link)
    except InvalidSessionIdException:
        new_driver = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor='http://localhost:4444',
            options=firefox_options
        )
        new_driver.set_window_size(1366, 784)
        drivers_list.append(new_driver)  #storing the new driver in our map of drivers
        driver = new_driver
    except WebDriverException:
        pass

    driver.get(current_link)
    
    ...further operation on the newly created driver...
```

The issue with this fix is that though it does create a new driver but it is never shown as running (in headless mode) and also, no websites gets assigned to it (basically it is never used).

Comment: how does the code know which driver it is getting if there are 16 of them ?

Comment: I am using a dictionary which maps each driver with its session id.